# date format getting system time format in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

in JQuery  we are getting system date format(example 05/may/2020, 05/05/2020, 5/520) . Can we restrict the date in  dd/mm/yyyy format only instead of system time format.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: [RTM](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization) - for example French